# angular-ui-select2: First time selecting a value shows empty label

Tags: angular-ui, ui-select2

Please look at this plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/hvQ6gflnNrpdcZfXSLMH/

When selecting an option for the first time, the option is selected, but the select2 shows empty label. Only when selecting the option for the second time the label appears.
I've checked the select2 without the use of angular-ui-select2 directive, and it works perfectly. I tried several versions of select2, and also tried ui-select2 versions 0.0.4 and 0.0.5.

Opened an issue on github: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/issues/239 but no comment so far, so I thought maybe the community could assist.

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, ui-select2 is incompatible with

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2#working-with-dynamic-options

Answer (score 0):

If you need an alternative that does work with dynamic options, you can check out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select. It's a native AngularJS version of select2 & selectize.